# What's the difference between "create" and "make" in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm learning Rails reading the Michael Hartl's web book (awesome source by the way), and he says that the "create" method  of a User Model's controller creates a user and the "new" method MAKES a user.

Alright... in the context of basic a User Model, and Rails in general, what really is the difference between "create" and "make"?

Thanks in advance for any feedback!

Answer (score 1):

Using the create method makes a user with the given parameter and saves it directly into the database, while using new makes a new user in memory that can be modified but has to be manually saved into the database by calling @user.save

Example try this in the rails console

```
User.create(name: "User 1", email: "example@example.com")
```

now type `User.all` and you'd find the user you created in the database.

Now try

```
a = User.new(name: User 2", email: "example2@example.com")
```

now typing `User.all` won't show this new user. You have to do `a.save` for it to be saved into the database.

Answer (score 0):

Just think of it as memory vs hard drive.  `User.new()` adds a new user record to memory (but does not save it to the database), while `User.create()` saves the record to the database.

You can do `user = User.new(); user.save;` and that would be equivalent to `User.create()`